# Two simultaneous generator functions, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator

I have two functions:

```
def a():
    while True:
        yield stuff

def b():
    while True:
        yield otherstuff
```

and I want to have a loop which collects one yield from each function stored in a for a() and b for b() ; for example. If I nest the for loops which call them, it restarts the 2nd generator every-time the first loop loops. Can I have any help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.izip(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to zip the values together.

```
>>> def a():
        for i in xrange(10):
            yield i


>>> def b():
        for i in xrange(10, 20):
            yield i


>>> from itertools import izip
>>> for i, j in izip(a(), b()):
        print i, j


0 10
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
6 16
7 17
8 18
9 19
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for x, y in zip(a(), b()):
```

It's just like simultaneously looping over any two sequences. (You may want to use `itertools.izip` or `from future_builtins import zip` to avoid gathering all the items into a big list before iterating.)

Comment: I don't think `zip(...)` would work with an infinite generator which seems to be OP's intent. Correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra: Huh. I didn't actually *read* the given generators; I probably should have. They are indeed infinite, so `izip` or future-zip would probably be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

```
from itertools import izip
z = izip(a(),b())
```

now you have generator of tuples, first item from a() and second from b()